# Paste skipping number of rows in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have to paste text content into Excel in a way that each row will be 12 rows apart of each other when I paste.

There will be content (plain text) on some of the skipped rows.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Original format:

```
profile.aboutme
profile.address1
profile.address2
profile.city
profile.country
(...)
```

Desired result

```
profile.aboutme
12 rows apart from:
profile.address1
12 rows apart from:
profile.address2
```

And so on...

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input data format and your desired output format.

Comment: @chishaku It's +900 rows of plain text.

Comment: Can you not paste a sample, e.g. 5, 10 rows?

Comment: Sometimes you need to help someone help you

Comment: @pnuts there are +900 rows to be pasted so I would need a macro to do this

Comment: @chishaku absolutely

Comment: Where does the 'content on some of the skipped rows' come from?

Comment: @chishaku content come from the plain text I just pasted. I need to paste using this method more than one time on the same row so I can achieve the right format for a database import. I will printscreen and attach it to the question so you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP requires a macro (though Q is not tagged as such) and has not provided the screenshot that might explain something of the skipped rows, but in case anyone is interested in a formula that does what the question asks:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),12)=1,INDIRECT("A"&1+(ROW()-1)/12),"")
```

copied down to suit (assuming "Original format" is in ColumnA, starting in A1).